# Questions on SQL Server hybrid solution authentication with 2 domains via Azure Application Proxy / Azure AD Guest users

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-ad-b2b, azure-appservice, azure-application-settings

One of our customer raised the below query:

They've got Azure VM (running SQL 2019 Analysis Services) connected to Azure AD via Azure Domain Services. It is on DomainX.com domain.

For Quest Users works well, when using B2B collaboration scenario in Azure service like PowerBI.com, They can share on-premise datasets with guest users and grant different level access as well in my local VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b

Question:

They need those same quest users to work with on-premise programs as well. For example quest.user@DomainY.com  is defined in DomainX.com Azure AD and they've set permissions in SQL Server Analysis Services (in local VM) for that user. Now this same person quest.user@DomainY.com  is logged into in his/hers personal computer in DomainY.com domain/network environment. They want local programs like Excel etc. to be able to connect to their VM and authenticate using the same quest accounts.

Basically they need help setting up this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/hybrid-cloud-to-on-premises

Any pointers would be of great help! Many thanks!

Comment: Hello Bala, did you encounter any issues while trying to set up Azure AD access to on-premises applications ?

Comment: AAD and guest users work/auth fine against customer's on-prem SQL Server Analysis Services when using PowerBI.com for instance. This works via B2B mechanism for Azure/O365 services.

I don’t have a local/on-prem AD at all. AAD in synced to on-prem SQL Server VM via Azure Domain Services. I need to get those guest users to auth directly to my on-prem SQL Server Analysis Services, running on TCP/IP from local programs like Excel or Power BI Desktop. 
Currently it works only if I use normal AAD user accounts in those computers.